# Синхронизация данных в базах данных

Tags: java, база-данных, сервер, http, embedded

Хочу импленментировать синхронизацию баз данных между удаленными машинами. Все происходит так: `embedded` система собирает данные и при возможности выхода в сеть `POST`-ит ее на сервер, сервер принимает `GET` запросы от клиентов, все в одностороннем порядке. Но не могу определиться с способом отправки данных на сервер с встроеной системы. Первое что приходит на ум:

- Встроенная система, при возможности подключиться к серверу, делает `GET` запрос и узнает какой последний id записи там лежит и делает выборку в своей базе всех записей которые были сделаны позже(т.е. имеют больше `id`) и постит все что не хватает.
- В встроенной системе, в самой безе данных, есть дополнительное поле которое хранит информацию о том была ли отправлена запись. Ну и если нет то отправлять.

Склоняюсь к второму варианту, т.к. не нужно делать дополнительные запросы. Буду рад альтернативным версиям и замечаниям, т.к. подобное проектирую в первый раз.

Comment: Если запись может изменяться а не только добавляться - то однозначно хранить в самой записи что она не отправлялась. но придется при отправке во всех записях этот признак менять. Возможно стоило бы пойти другим путем, ввести некий постоянно растущий id транзакции, во всех записях писать id в момент ее последней модификации. Отправлять не сервер в порядке этих id. при записи сервер сообщает id который он точно отразил у себя. его можно сохранять прямо на клиенте, что бы в следующий раз начать передачу с него. Как дополнение можно предусмотреть ответ от сервера "повтори с номера"

Comment: @Mike, интересная идея, т.е. хранить на самом клиенте последний отправленый успешно id, при этом отпадает надобность у GET-е. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да, так. А возможность запросить с сервера с другого номера скорее для случая если у вас на сервере что то пойдет не так, что то потеряется и захотите иметь возможность восстановить инфу

Comment: @Mike, мне кажеться это то что нужно, спасибо! Можете оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю ввести некий постоянно растущий id транзакции (или использовать время с точностью до миллисекунд). Во время добавления/модификации какой либо записи на клиенте писать в нее этот id. Во время сеанса связи с сервером отправлять данные в порядке этих id. В ответ, при получении информации и успешной записи, сервер сообщает id последней обработанной записи. Этот id записывать где нибудь на клиенте. При следующем сеансе связи клиент начинает передавать данные начиная с сохраненного id.

В протоколе общения так же можно предусмотреть запрос последнего id с сервера, на случай, если клиент его по какой то причине потерял. Так же может оказаться полезной (на случай восстановления после сбоев или отладки) возможность при любом запросе к серверу, в ответ прислать информацию, заставляющую клиент сбросить текущий id на более раннюю позицию и присылать данные, начиная с него.