# Как организовать правильно процесс наблюдения за изменениями в таблицах в базе

Tags: sql, sql-server-localdb

Есть внешняя база с данными, в приложении я загружаю данные в локальную базу localDB и работаю с данными.
Есть в базе локальной 10 таблиц. Мне нужно знать, что в каждой из этих таблиц произошло, то есть какие строки удалились, какие обновились, а какие добавились. Мне неважно, кто это сделал. Далее мне нужно получить от локальной базы список всех измененных записей. Этот список я получаю в приложении, далее в приложении я строю запрос на основании этого списка,и отправлю во внешнюю базу данных,чтобы там тоже были изменения. Мое приложение не имеет возможности подключиться на прямую к внешней базе. Вопросы:
Верна ли логика построения такого аудита. Я создаю триггер на каждую таблицу, который реагирует на insert,update,delete. Можно ли создать один триггер на все таблицы с такой функцией? Все данные я записываю в таблицу Аудит. И в таблице, есть только поле именно  внутренний идентификатор поля(типа rowid) и Идентификатор в самой таблице типа OID. И еще что за действие было совершено.
Далее можно сделать внутреннюю процедуру,которая выдаст мне в моем приложении эти данные, а дальше я уже делаю запрос на основе этого  во внешнюю базу и говорю ей, какие записи нужно изменить и на что, какие добавить, а какие удалить. Подскажите как лучше все это организовать.

Comment: Думаю вполне можно обойтись почти одинаковыми (но конечно не одним) триггерами, если поля первичного ключа одинаково называются. Фиксировать в аудите только что за таблица, первичный ключ и тип изменения. Данные можно будет получить из самой таблицы. Триггера можно сгенерировать скриптом, на любом внешнем языке. Все отличие в триггерах - имя (id) таблицы. ну и названия полей первичного ключа, если они вдруг разные

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответ, да я тоже думаю,что имею информацию о таблице и измененой строки, сами данные можно вытянуть уже в приложении

Comment: См. так же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/940617/194569